# The scrollToSection method does not scroll

Tags: sapui5

I have a `ObjectPageLayout` that is divided two sections, that it looks like:

```
<Page id="floatingFooterPage" enableScrolling="false" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onNavButtonPress">
    <content>
        <uxap:ObjectPageLayout id="ClassDetail" showHeaderContent="true">
            <uxap:headerTitle>
                <uxap:ObjectPageHeader></uxap:ObjectPageHeader>
            </uxap:headerTitle>
            <uxap:headerContent>
                <f:SimpleForm editable="false" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" singleContainerFullSize="false">
                    <f:content>
                        <Label text="{i18n>charsClass}"/>
                        <Text text="{ClassInfo>/classNum} {ClassInfo>/classNumDescr}"/>
                        <Label text="{i18n>charsClassType}"/>
                        <Text text="{ClassInfo>/classType} {ClassInfo>/classTypeText}"/>
                    </f:content>
                </f:SimpleForm>
            </uxap:headerContent>
            <uxap:sections>
                <uxap:ObjectPageSection title="{i18n>charsCharsSel}" id="SecChars">
                    <uxap:subSections>
                        <uxap:ObjectPageSubSection >
                            <uxap:blocks>
                                <mvc:XMLView width="100%" viewName="ch.mindustrie.ZMM_OBJECTS_CLASSES.view.CharacSelection" id="CharacSelection"/>
                            </uxap:blocks>
                        </uxap:ObjectPageSubSection>
                    </uxap:subSections>
                </uxap:ObjectPageSection>
                <uxap:ObjectPageSection title="{i18n>charsObject}" id="SecObject">
                    <uxap:subSections>
                        <uxap:ObjectPageSubSection >
                            <uxap:blocks>
                                <mvc:XMLView width="100%" viewName="ch.mindustrie.ZMM_OBJECTS_CLASSES.view.ObjectTable" id="ObjectTable"/>
                            </uxap:blocks>
                        </uxap:ObjectPageSubSection>
                    </uxap:subSections>
                </uxap:ObjectPageSection>
                <!--    <uxap:ObjectPageSection title="Sub classes" id="SecSub" visible="false">
                    <uxap:subSections>
                        <uxap:ObjectPageSubSection >
                            <uxap:blocks>
                                <mvc:XMLView width="100%" viewName="ch.mindustrie.ZMM_OBJECTS_CLASSES.view.ClassTree" id="SubTree"/>
                            </uxap:blocks>
                        </uxap:ObjectPageSubSection>
                    </uxap:subSections>
                </uxap:ObjectPageSection>-->
            </uxap:sections>
        </uxap:ObjectPageLayout>
    </content>
    <footer>
        <Toolbar>
            <ToolbarSpacer/>
            <Button id="FindObject" text="{i18n>charsObject}" press="onPress" type="Transparent"/>
        </Toolbar>
    </footer>
</Page>
```

I wanted to scroll to section `SecChars` programmatically and I have done as following:

```
_scrollToObjectSection: function () {
    const oObjPage = this.byId("ClassDetail");
    oObjPage.scrollToSection("SecObject", 0, 0);
}
```

But it does not work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2408

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issues

1. The API `scrollToSection` awaits a global ID (the suffix `"SecObject"` alone is not enough). So it should be:

   ```js
   oObjPage.scrollToSection(this.byId("SecObject").getId());
   ```
2. That API, however, can be only successfully performed when the DOM of the ObjectPageLayout is fully ready. I added "fully" because calling `scrollToSection` within the `onAfterRendering` event delegate won't do anything either. There must be an additional timeout of about `450` ms. It's nowhere documented though how many milliseconds are actually required, and there is no **public** event for this case either.

## Alternatives

- Use [`setSelectedSection`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout/methods/setSelectedSection) instead, as mentioned in the documentation topic [*Object Page Scrolling*](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/bc410e94e46540efa02857e15aae583f). The ObjectPageLayout will scroll to that section, but currently without any scrolling animation (`iDuration = 0`). The "selectedSection" is an association, hence, it can be also set within the view definition:

  ```xml
  <uxap:ObjectPageLayout selectedSection="mySection">
    <uxap:ObjectPageSection id="mySection">
  ```
- Keep using `scrollToSection` but leverage the **<sub><sup>⚠️</sup></sub> private** event `"onAfterRenderingDOMReady"`[(src)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/7759b64c7a38d1e60c65c2da44ea052976f88d02) which is fired when the DOM is fully ready:

  ```js
  onInit: function() {
    // ...
    this.scrollTo(this.byId("mySection"), this.byId("myObjectPageLayout"));
  },

  scrollTo: function(section, opl) {
    const id = section.getId();
    const ready = !!opl.getScrollingSectionId(); // DOM of opl is fully ready
    const fn = () => opl.scrollToSection(id);
    return ready ? fn() : opl.attachEventOnce("onAfterRenderingDOMReady", fn);
  },
  ```

  The API [`getScrollingSectionId()`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.uxap.ObjectPageLayout/methods/getScrollingSectionId) returns a falsy value (currently `""`) if the DOM is **not** fully ready.